# is there a table or something that maps each zoom level to a polyline stroke width

Tags: android, zooming, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline

I am going to implement a map application and I have a camerachange listener from which I can get the current zoom level. I would then set the polyline stroke width of the road to cover the width  of roads in the map。 The problem is that I don't know what proper width I should set to polyline. Given that, is there any formal mapping methods or document in Android that can help me set a width per zoom level?